# Binding boolean DependencyProperty to a button's Visibility property in Generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I have a class called CarSystemWindow that descends from Window, and it has a CanPinWindow boolean dependency property:

```
public class CarSystemWindow : Window {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanPinWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "CanPinWindow", typeof( bool ), typeof( CarSystemWindow ),
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange ) );

    public bool CanPinWindow {
        get { return (bool) GetValue( CanPinWindowProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( CanPinWindowProperty, value ); }
    }

    . . .
}
```

In Generic.xaml, I have defined the default style for the CarSystemWindow class:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
                    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:Telerik_Windows_Controls_Chromes="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chromes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls">

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisbility" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CarSystemWindow}">
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CarSystemWindow}">
                    <Viewbox Name="LayoutRoot"  Stretch="Uniform">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid Background="#FF3C4B66" Height="50" Name="PART_Title">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
                                       FontSize="32" 
                                       Foreground="White" 
                                       Grid.Column="0" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Name="PART_TitleLabel" />
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Margin="5" 
                                        Name="PART_PushpinButton" 
                                        Visibility="{Binding CanPinWindow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisbility}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                    <Image Name="PART_PushpinImage" Source="/CarSystem;component/Resources/Unpinned.png" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" 
                                        Margin="5" 
                                        Name="PART_MinimizeButton">
                                    <Image Name="PART_MinimizeButtonImage" Source="/CarSystem;component/Resources/Minimize.png" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="3" 
                                        Margin="5" 
                                        Name="PART_CloseButton">
                                    <Image Name="PART_CloseButtonImage" Source="/CarSystem;component/Resources/Close.png" />
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>

                            <Rectangle Fill="#FFE61E0F" Height="4" Name="PART_TitleBar" />

                            <Grid Background="#FF3C4B66" Height="25" Name="PART_SubTitle">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding DeviceType}" 
                                       FontSize="22" 
                                       Foreground="White" 
                                       Grid.Column="0" 
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                                       Margin="5" 
                                       MinWidth="75" 
                                       Name="PART_DeviceTypeLabel" />
                                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding DeviceName}" 
                                       FontSize="22" 
                                       Foreground="White" 
                                       Grid.Column="1" 
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                       Margin="5" 
                                       MinWidth="250" 
                                       Name="PART_DeviceNameLabel" />
                                <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Column="2" Name="PART_SubTitleRight" />
                            </Grid>

                            <Rectangle Fill="#FF3C4B66" Height="4" Name="PART_TitleBottom" />

                            <ContentPresenter Name="PART_ClientArea" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    . . .

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The binding for the PART_PushpinButton Button's Visibiility property isn't working.  The button is always visible, even though the property defaults to false.  What am I doing wrong?

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `RelativeSource` should be `TemplatedParent`, not `Self`. Or am I missing some part of your code?

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="5" 
    Name="PART_PushpinButton" 
    Visibility="{Binding CanPinWindow, Converter= {StaticResource BoolToVisbility}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```